# Trying to get .htaccess to redirect to https but conflicting with existing redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, https

I'v just activated an SSL Certificate on a site and went to add the usual .htaccess redirect info.

However, there's an existing .htaccess file with a whole set of redirects already in place (I'll attach at the bottom).

When I try to add the https re-direct it keeps trying to redirect and eventually gives up…
Is there a way to keep add the https redirect in?

Here's the existing .htaccess file contents:

```
#php_value auto_prepend_file    /kunden/homepages/8/d130052251/htdocs/kralinator/hosted/bellemellor/admin/psycho.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Rewrites...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^=]*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} %2d|\- [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F,L]

#JS/CSS combinator
RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*\.css) admin/combine.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/js/(.*\.js) admin/combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
#RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) combine.php?type=css&files=$1
#RewriteRule ^js/(.*\.js) combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1

#Pages
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?level1=$1 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?    level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3&level4=$4 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3&level4=$4&level5=$5 [L,QSA]
```

I added the https redirect in different locations in the file but to no avail.
I'm a front-end developer and haven't encountered this before as I normally only have the basic https redirect in a .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/index.php$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but to no avail" - What happens exactly? This rule needs to go at the top of the file, otherwise it's not going to do anything. But why have you included `index.php` in the target URL?

Comment: Tried without index.php I get this message:
Too many redirects occurred trying to open “‎bellemellor.com”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page, which then is redirected to open the original page.

Comment: Seems to be working OK for me (a temporary 302 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS) - have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Solved it. There was a config file that was being loaded which was set to https false which jut sent everything back and forth… Changed that and all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
There was a config file that was being loaded which was set to https false which jut sent everything back and forth…
Changed that and all good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. It will redirect any URL on port 80 to the https version. Then your other htaccess rewrites should still work too.

This will need to be placed at the top below **RewriteBase /**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tried this, I get. this message:
Too many redirects occurred trying to open “‎bellemellor.com”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page, which then is redirected to open the original page.